# presentModalViewController vs. pushViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I can show a different view with this code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:childView animated:nil];
```

This code should do the same thing, right?

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];
```

But it doesn't do anything. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pushViewController only works in navigation controllers

presentModalViewController works for all view controllers