# Best way to add a UIViewController on top of another UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

What is the best way to add a UIViewController on top of a UIViewController which is already present on my iPhone. There are two ways I know of. But is there a better way? Which one of these is better, if not?

```
1. [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
2. [self.view addSubview:someController.view];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[self view] addSubview: [otherViewController view]];

CGRect frame = [[self view] frame];

int direction = 1;
switch (direction) {
    case 0: // from bottom
        frame.origin.y = [[self view] frame].size.height;
        [[otherViewController view] setFrame: frame];
        frame.origin.y = 0.0 - [[self view] frame].size.height;
        break;
    case 1: // from right
        frame.origin.x = [[self view] frame].size.width;
        [[otherViewController view] setFrame: frame];
        frame.origin.x = 0.0 - [[self view] frame].size.width;
        break;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [[self view] setFrame: frame];
                 }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {

                 }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you want to implement it. If you want to show the view controller and dismiss it using existing transitions, you can use *presentModalViewController*. But, if you want to show it with some custom animations, you can use *addSubView*. And again, it entirely depends on you.

Comment: So if I had a UIViewController and I wanted to add a subview, how could I animate it? For instance, making a UIButton fly in from the right?

Comment: @StanLe, You can use UIView animations. See this link, http://objcolumnist.com/2009/07/18/simple-uiview-based-animations-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on your requirement of showing view controller.
There could be one more pushing the controller in navigation stack.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```

Check appl forum post for when to use `pushViewController:` and when `presentModalViewController:` .

[pushViewController versus presentModalViewController](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12484209?messageID=12484209)

[presentModalViewController vs. pushViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740056/presentmodalviewcontroller-vs-pushviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Both of the way, are almost equivalent, as the make a stack of views, you can see the beneath view(till not been alkaline) by, `[self removeFromSuperview]`, when you `addSubView`, and `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, when yo use `[self presentModalViewController:tempView animated:NO];`, But Yea `presentModalViewController`, give you default option for animation whether with `addSubview`, you need to work a bit for that.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you want. No one way is better than the other. All are just... ways.